# How to make a material pattern on clothes resembling the original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I get the following line of code to change the color of the fabric, but the problem is the color of the material does not follow the pattern on the clothing model. if I refer to a clothing site, they can change the color of the clothing material to resemble the original (https://www.tailorstore.com/). how to do this. thank you for the help.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=800></canvas>

<script>
var img1 = new Image, 
    img2 = new Image, 
    cnt = 2,
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

img1.onload = img2.onload = function() {
    if (!--cnt) go()
};

img1.src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/86/2f/37/862f37a3919ee3288c458a1a23ba756a.png";
img2.src = "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/82560777/resize-h800%5Ecompr-r85/8420/84209861/Vita+Basic+Removable+Peel+and+Stick+Wallpaper+Panel.jpg";

function go() {
    // create a pattern  
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(img2, "repeat");
    // fill canvas with pattern
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // use blending mode multiply
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    // draw sofa on top
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, img1.width*.5, img1.height * .5);
    // change composition mode
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    // draw to cut-out sofa
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, img1.width * .5, img1.height * .5);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

And this is what is on the referral site:

[image]

I really hope there is someone who can help me provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: please can you remove the website from your message (https://www.tailorstore.com/), it could be considered spam.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you need help with, this code does exactly what it's supposed to. 'img1' is a blank model canvas and 'img2' is the pattern. In this case the pattern displayed above.

I replaced the pattern with a matching blue image instead

```
img2.src = "https://www.beautycolorcode.com/829bca.png";
```

which give me this

[image]

Comment: please access this address: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b3/e2/44/b3e2449bd652a9d57b2dfdf16de6a2e8.png. it can be seen that the pattern of the shirt lines (straight line down) is different from the pattern of the collar lines (straight as in the horizontal direction). this is what I'm asking. how to do it?

Comment: Find an image with a similar partern, replace the url for img2 with the url to the image you have found.